# TFS backup job hangs - how do i find the problem?

Tags: tfs, sql-server-2016

I have TFS backup job hangs for several hours without any errors.

I have tried Restart of SQL server.

On the monitoring page of TFS it looks ok without any errors.

- TFS 2018.1
- SQL SERVER 2016 STD
- Windows Server 2012 R2

Backup was working good as scheduled for almost 1 year.